# Why is table td automatically going to max-width: none

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have a table where I need fixed td sizes and as such I have the appropriate `table-layout: fixed`, `white-space: nowrap`, `overflow:hidden`, etc etc on the table and td's.  It was working great until I had to dynamically resize it by basically adding a row at runtime

Basically I use javascript to add a row

```
<tr>
  <td style="max-width:50px; min-width:50px; width:50px">&nbsp;</td>
  <td style="max-width:50px; min-width:50px; width:50px">&nbsp;</td>
  <td style="max-width:50px; min-width:50px; width:50px">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

It didn't work because some of the table td's are overflowing now.  Well it turns out the td's even after this row somehow inherit as`max-width: none`.  When I manually add `max-width:50px` to an offending overflow td in firebug, the layout gets fixed.

Why is it ignoring the rules I set on the first tr and how can I set all td's to obey?

edit:
here is the fix width code as requested (there are two tables in the tableDiv):

```
fixWidths : function(tableDiv)
{
    var headerTable = tableDiv.find('.headertable');
    var widths = [];
    headerTable.find("th").each(function(){
        widths.push($(this).width());
    });

    var tr = tableDiv.find('.fixwidth');
    for (var i = 0; i < widths.length; ++i)
    {
        var td = $(document.createElement('th'));
        td.css('width', widths[i]);
        td.css('min-width', widths[i]);
        td.css('max-width', widths[i]);
        td.html('&nbsp;');
        tr.append(td);
    }
    /* */

}
```

Comment: Please post the code you're referring to that dynamically changes the layout.

Comment: You retrieve the widths as plain numbers (e.g. `50`), but properties like `min-width` require units, like `50px`.

Comment: You mentioned you have your `table-layout: fixed`. This is going to cause overflow rather than an expansion of the table itself. Try setting the `table-layout:auto` and tell us what happens.